# Passing reference parameter in objective C

Tags: objective-c

I am currently developing a project that interact with sqlite database. The problem is every time I want to connect to database, i have to open and prepare the database. So I want to make those step more generic and I decided to make a common class that will do those steps for me.

```
+(void)openAndPrepareDatabase:(sqlite3 *)db andStatement:(sqlite3_stmt *)statement andSql:(const char *)sql
{
@try
{
    if(!sqlite3_open([[self getDatabasePath] UTF8String], &db) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        NSException *myException = [NSException exceptionWithName:@"Can't open database" reason:@"Can't open database" userInfo:Nil];

        @throw myException;
    }

    if(!sqlite3_prepare(db, sql, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        NSException *myException = [NSException exceptionWithName:@"Can't prepare database" reason:@"Can't prepare database" userInfo:Nil];

        @throw myException;
    }
}
@catch (NSException *exception)
{
    @throw exception;
}
}


+(void)openAndPrepareDatabaseV2:(sqlite3 *)db andStatement:(sqlite3_stmt *)statement andSql:(const char *)sql
{
@try
{
    if(!sqlite3_open([[self getDatabasePath] UTF8String], &db) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        NSException *myException = [NSException exceptionWithName:@"Can't open database" reason:@"Can't open database" userInfo:Nil];

        @throw myException;
    }

    if(!sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, sql, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        NSException *myException = [NSException exceptionWithName:@"Can't prepare database" reason:@"Can't prepare database" userInfo:Nil];

        @throw myException;
    }
}
@catch (NSException *exception)
{
    @throw exception;
}
}
```

But when I try to call it in my object, I.E:

```
[Common openAndPrepareDatabase:&db andStatement:&statement andSql:sql];
```

I got a warning:

```
"Incompatible pointer types sending 'sqlite3_stmt **' (aka 'struct sqlite3_stmt **')  to parameter of type 'sqlite3_stmt *' (aka 'struct sqlite3_stmt *'); remove &"
```

Does anyone knows a solution for my problem?

Comment: Why don't you read the error message before copy-pasting it, by the way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does anyone knows a solution for my problem?

The compiler has ***just shown you one.***

> "incompatible pointer ... blah blah; ***remove &***"

(emphasis mine)

Comment: After remove "&", do those codes above behave like when i open and prepare database on my object (not through common class)?

Comment: @DoanCuong I don't understand the question, and you don't understand pointers.

Comment: I want to know that after passing db and statement parameter to those methods (and remove "&", of course), can I use them to do further processes like binding sql parameter and executing the query on my object or not

Comment: @DoanCuong That depends on how the variable of which the address you pass in is defined.

Comment: @DoanCuong Google "automatic storage duration".

Comment: I found the solution, thank you. But may I ask one more question? Which solution would be best? Passing a pointer or returning a struct?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25589/discussion-between-h2co3-and-doan-cuong)

Comment: @DoanCuong In this case I think passing pointers around is preferred